# How to check CRC16-CCITT remainder?

Tags: crc16

I implemented CRC16-CCITT that reduces to finding the remainder of the
division by g(x) = x16 + x12 + x5 + 1. Now how can i check if crc is good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the CRC on the message, and compare that to the CRC sent with the message.